# AngularJS.Вызов метода контролера внутри разметки HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

есть разметка

```
<div class="col-md-2 card-container" 
            ng-init="over=false; rating = film.Like - film.DisLike"
            ng-mouseover="over=true;" 
            ng-mouseleave="over=false;" 
            ng-repeat="film in lastUpdate">
        <div class="col-md-12 hover-info" ng-show="over">
            <button class="fa fa-bars film-modal-info" ng-click="showInfoModal();"></button>
            <button class="fa fa-play play-film"></button>
            <div class="rating">
                <button  
                        class="fa fa-thumbs-up like" 
                        ng-click="rating=thisLike(film.FilmId);"></button>
                <div>
                    <span ng-class="{'low-rating':rating < 0}" 
                          class="rating-count">{{ rating }}</span>
                </div>
                <button  
                        class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike" 
                        ng-click="rating=thisDisLike(film.FilmId)"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="card-img-film" 
             ng-src="{{ film.Poster }}">
    </div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку вызываю метод из контролера

```
ng-click="rating=thisLike(film.FilmId);"
```

Сам метод

```
$scope.thisLike = async function(id){
        let v = await setRating.Like(id);
        console.log(v);
        return v;
    }
```

Если console то в нее выводиться что мне надо.
результат пишет в переменную rating которая инициализированна в самом начале разметки.

```
ng-init="over=false; rating = film.Like - film.DisLike"
```

после генерации разметки  все верно отображается.
Но если нажать кнопку вместо цифры(рейтинг типа) пишется

```
{}
```

Просто две фигурные скобки

В чем проблема? Если определить переменную в контролере то она не меняется.Это из того что она в разметке определенна?
пробывал `ng-bind` тоже самое

Comment: это из-за того, что у функции стоит async, и на самом деле она возвращает Promise

Comment: без async он не успевает ответ получить и уже возвращает значение

Comment: У тебя в любом случае функция возвращает Promise. ты можешь попробовать дописать await при вызове. но скорее всего ангуляр это не поймет. Вместо этого, ты можешь устанавливать значение _внутри_ вызова.